# Automatically rollback two-phase transactions on session disconnect

Tags: postgresql, distributed-transactions

I'm using two-phase commit in Postgres to reliably work with an external system (Amazon EC2).

I.e. I first do a PREPARE call, then call the external system. If the external system call fails for some reason, I simply rollback the prepared transaction.

It works fine. However, if I terminate my application while a distributed transaction is open, it will hang forever. Is it possible to automatically rollback 2PC transactions on session disconnection?

Comment: Wouldn't that destroy the whole point of using a prepared transaction?

Comment: Not in my particular use-case. If I terminate my application then the external call is also going to be terminated. It's not possible to recover it later.

Comment: I think what you are doing is completely equivalent to leaving the transaction open while calling the external service.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, it seems impossible after reading PostgreSQL source code. I settled for rolling back all the prepared transactions during application initialization.

Python code is:

```
def cleanup_prepared_xas(engine):
    conn = engine.connect()
    trs = [t[0] for t in conn.execute('select gid from pg_prepared_xacts')]
    conn.execute("rollback;")
    for t in trs:
        conn.rollback_prepared(t)
    conn.close()
```